# cannot parseInt in React project keep getting NaN

Tags: reactjs, parseint

[image]
Ok, so I am currently trying to add items from an object together prices to be exact. When I try to actually parse the items with parseInt,I keep getting NaN.

I have tried to replicate it on repl.it and it works fine, also I have tried to use Number instead of parseInt and same results.

```
    class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCart();
    }

    add(array) {
        let num = [];
        let parse = [];
        console.log(array);
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            parse.push(array[i].price);
        }
        console.log(parse);
        for (let i = 0; i < parse.length; i++) {
            num.push(parseInt(parse[i]));
        }
        console.log(num);
        let sum = num.reduce((acc, val) => {
            return acc + val;
        }, 0);
        console.log(sum);
    }
    render() {
        const { cart } = this.props.itemReducer;
                this.add(cart);
```

I do have a few console.log's 
first one does show my obj's 
the second show's that I pulled my numbers in the variable["$379.99", "$1,499.99"]
the third one where I actually do the parseInt function is when i get [NaN, NaN]`

Comment: It's probably not working because you have a dollar sign in front and comma seperators for your value. Try removing the commas and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `["$379.99", "$1,499.99"]`, here items in array contains `$` which is not a number (NaN) causing the error.

Instead of this,

```
num.push(parseInt(parse[i]));
```

You can do this,

```
num.push(Number(parse[i].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")));
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/lehojafobo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks a lot totally looked at it 50 times and totally skipped over that $ sign.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `$` sign in your string. Remove the sign and try

```js
let nanNum = parseInt("$1477")
console.log(nanNum) //This will print NaN

let parsedNum = parseInt("$147,7.05".replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""))
console.log(parsedNum)
```

Comment: @ravibagul91 It works without any change. Updated answer with suggested value

Comment: It is removing `.05` from value.

Comment: It is parseInt so isn't it expected to remove decimals?